# boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open causes exit code 3 on Windows but works in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw, memory-mapped-files

I'm using `mapped_file_source` from the `boost::iostreams` `namespace` to read from a large file in chunks:

```
boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source read_bytes(const char *file_path,
                                                unsigned long long int offset,
                                                unsigned long long int length) {
    iostreams::mapped_file_params parameters;
    parameters.path = file_path;
    parameters.length = static_cast<size_t>(length);
    parameters.flags = iostreams::mapped_file::mapmode::readonly;
    parameters.offset = static_cast<boost::iostreams::stream_offset>(offset);

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file;

    file.open(parameters);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        return file;
    } else {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

My code works fine for `Ubuntu` in `WSL` (`Windows Subsystem for Linux`) but when I compile and run it on Windows, the 2nd `file.open` call causes the process to exit with exit code `3`.

```
Reading file in 5 parts
Processing chunk 1/5
Processing chunk 2/5

Process finished with exit code 3
```

No error message or exception has been caused. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) suggests it to be `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` but that makes no sense.

I debugged both platform binaries and all variables are exactly identical with the only exceptions being the `Unix` style file path and the `Windows` style path as well as allocated addresses and system time variables so no memory corruption has occurred. I do not understand why this doesn't work on `Windows` when it should behave identically.

I'm using [`MinGW`](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) to compile for `Windows` and `gcc 8.2` in `Ubuntu`.

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If I read the file in a single go, it works fine (!). I'm aligning all offsets to page size multiples. The `mapped_file_source` is automatically closed when it falls out of scope so it's not a "file already open" issue (that would actually cause an exception by `Boost`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`MSVC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) the problem can no longer be reproduced now. In general, using `Microsoft`'s compiler for `Windows` may be more reliable than the likes of `MinGW`, especially since I was using [an "unofficial" toolchain](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html).